# HighCharts: Compare the series data with each other and show percentage

Tags: highcharts

I am working with highcharts and I have to display the series data in form of the percentage. considering first series data as total value and for another calculate its percentage with respect to total

e.g

```
series: [{
        name: 'Total value',
        data: [50,100,50,100,50,]
      }, {
        name: 'Value 1',
        data: [5,20,10,62,31,]
      }]
```

I have these values for series data and need to calculate the percentage for value1 field which will be (5*100)/50=20% (50 is consider as total value)

same for all values. I have tried many ways but it considers total value as 50+5, i.e the total of both data fields respectively.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I have uploaded the highchart at link

```
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {type: 'area' },

  xAxis: { categories: ['A','B','C','D','E',] },
  yAxis: {  min: 0,
    allowDecimals: false,
    title: { text: ' Count'}, },
    tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b>  ',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}:  {point.y}<br> ({point.percentage:.1f}%)'
  },
plotOptions: {
  column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0,stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,},},
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',}}, 
  series: [{
    name: 'Total value',
    data: [50,100,50,100,50,]
  }, {
    name: 'Value 1',
    data: [5,20,10,62,31,]}]});
```

Comment: Also i have uploaded the code at below link https://jsfiddle.net/yc6ksz54/14/

Comment: Hi Meenu Garg, do you want display percentage value for the second series in tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you are after by using a [`pointFormatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter) in the tooltip, like this:

```
pointFormatter: function() {
  return this.series.name + ": " + this.y + "<br/>(" + this.y * 100 / this.series.chart.series[0].data[this.x].y + "%)"
}
```

Additionaly, if you move the tooltip formatting inside the series, you will only have the tooltip display for the series you want in that way, and not for the total series. Like this:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Total value',
  data: [50, 100, 50, 100, 50, ]
}, {
  name: 'Value 1',
  data: [5, 20, 10, 62, 31, ],
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b>  ',
    pointFormatter: function() {
      return this.series.name + ": " + this.y + "<br/>(" + this.y * 100 / this.series.chart.series[0].data[this.x].y + "%)"
    }
  }
}]
```

```js
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'area'
      },

      xAxis: {
        categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', ]
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
          text: ' Count'
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0,
          stacking: 'normal',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          },
        },
        series: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Total value',
        data: [50, 100, 50, 100, 50, ]
      }, {
        name: 'Value 1',
        data: [5, 20, 10, 62, 31, ],
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b>  ',
          pointFormat: '{series.name}:  {point.y}<br> ({point.percentage:.1f}%)',
          pointFormatter: function() {
            return this.series.name + ": " + this.y + "<br/>(" + this.y * 100 / this.series.chart.series[0].data[this.x].y + "%)"
          }
        }
      }]
    });
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/eudhkgp3/